# Flexible box not working as expected

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, stylesheet

Ok, I am using Chrome for this.

I have a div on which i defined `display: -webkit-box;`. Inside of this div there are 7 divs which all have `-webkit-box-flex: 1;`.

The first div, however, is smaller than the others. Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: Your code please.

Comment: I created a cssdesk preview: http://cssdesk.com/rxRum

This works fine on chrome. The boxes are nearly equal size. Please take this as a start to refine your question.

Comment: You are right, actually I was mistaken. I guess webkit-box-flex will fill the remaining space. My first element had no text, the others did, that's why it was smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearantly I misunderstood the box model. I was confused at the time and thought all divs would be equal, but actually it is the remaining space that is being added equally.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think 7 boxes in an 80% width div will give you evenly spaced columns. Even playing with the border of the last column, or setting the parent to 960px. 7 just doesn't go into it evenly